# docker varnish cmd error - no such file or directory

Tags: docker-compose, varnish

I'm trying to get a Varnish container running as part of a multicontainer Docker environment.

I'm using https://github.com/newsdev/docker-varnish as a base.

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM newsdev/varnish:4.1.0

COPY start-varnishd.sh /usr/local/bin/start-varnishd

ENV VARNISH_VCL_PATH /etc/varnish/default.vcl
ENV VARNISH_PORT 80
ENV VARNISH_MEMORY 64m

EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "exec /usr/local/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=varnishd -F -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,64m -a 0.0.0.0:80 -p http_req_hdr_len=16384 -p http_resp_hdr_len=16384" ]
```

When I run this as part of a docker-compose setup, I get:

> ERROR: for eventsapi_varnish_1  Cannot start service varnish: oci
>   runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process
>   caused "exec: \"exec /usr/local/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=varnishd -F
>   -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,64m -a 0.0.0.0:80 -p http_req_hdr_len=16384 -p http_resp_hdr_len=16384\": stat exec
>   /usr/local/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=varnishd -F -f
>   /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,64m -a 0.0.0.0:80 -p
>   http_req_hdr_len=16384 -p http_resp_hdr_len=16384: no such file or
>   directory"

I get the same if I try

```
CMD ["start-varnishd"]
```

(as it is in the base newsdev/docker-varnish)

or

```
CMD [/usr/local/bin/start-varnishd]
```

But if I run a bash shell on the container directly:

```
docker run -t -i eventsapi_varnish /bin/bash
```

and then run the varnishd command from there, varnish starts up fine (and starts complaining that it can't find the web container, obviously).

What am I doing wrong? What file can't it find? Again looking around the running container directly, it seems that Varnish is where it thinks it should be, the VCL file is where it thinks it should be... what's stopping it running from within docker-compose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get to the bottom of why I was getting this error, but "fixed" it by using the (more recent?) fork: https://hub.docker.com/r/tripviss/varnish/. My Dockerfile is now just:

```
FROM tripviss/varnish:5.1

COPY default.vcl /usr/local/etc/varnish/
```